# overriding tr onclick

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I've got the following code in a django template:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <tr onclick="{% url collection:viewitem item_id=item.id %}">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="{% url collection:edititem item_id=item.id %}" type="button">Edit</button>
      <button onclick="{% url collection:removeitem item_id=item.id %}" type="button">Remove</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However, the button `onclick` events don't work, because the tr `onclick` seems to override it.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

please try the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table >
            <tr onclick="alert('tr');">
                <td><input type="button" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;alert('input');"/></td>
            </tr>
        <table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The **event.cancelBubble=true** will suppress the tr click event

Answer (score 2):

Using `event.stopPropagation()` will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

An other approach:
Create a separate row for the button so it wont inherit the tr onclick event of the main row. Something like this:

```
<tr onclick="doSomething()">
   <td rowspan="2">A</td>
   <td rowspan="2">B</td>
   <td rowspan="2">C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><button type="button">Click</button></td>
 </tr>
```